# Elementary questions regarding countable sets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

can somebody help me correct my attempts at proving the following result? Much appreciated.

**Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is a nonempty finite set. Let $n$ be the least natural number such that there is a one-to-one function $f: X \rightarrow $ {$1,2,3,...,n$}. With the number of elements in $X$ being |$X$|$=n$, prove that $f$ must be onto.

**My Attempt:**

Suppose for contradiction that $f$ is not onto,then there exist some elements in the codomain {$1,2,3,...,n$} such that no elements of the domain map to them. Let $1 \le i \le n$ be the largest element of the codomain such that $i \notin ran(f)$.

[case $i=n$]. If $i=n$, then by definition $n \notin ran(f)$.Since n is the least natural number that ensures $f$ to be one-to-one, it must be the case that $n \in ran(f)$ providing the contradiction sought.

[case $i<n$]  the book gives the hint :

> if $i<n$,let $a \in X$ be such that $f(a)=n$.Define a one-to-one
>   function $g : X\rightarrow$ {$1,2,...,n-1$}.

Hence i thought : With $i<n$ and by definition $i \notin ran(f)$ but $n \in ran(f)$,there is an element $a \in X$ such that $f(a)=n$. With $|X|=n$,the number of elements in the domain and codomain are the same,therefore if there is no element in $X$ that maps to $i \in $ {$1,2,3,...,n-1$} then $f$ cannot be one-to-one...but where is g?

this feels wrong but i do not know what to do!
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't even get the theorem statement. Did you miss-type something?

Comment: Does it basically say that if X is in a bijection with {0..n} and {0..n'} for some natural number n,n' then n = n'?

Comment: define $g(a)=i$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ otherwise

Comment: That is not what "countable" means! You should say "finite sets" instead.

Comment: amrsa..so basically g:X->{1,2,3,...,n-1} where g(a)=i and g(x)=f(x) otherwise?? i still do not understand....suppose X={b,c,d,a} then f:X->{1,2,3,n=4} is one-to-one, where b is mapped to 1 ,c mapped to 2,etc...now suppose by contradiction that f i not onto and consider the case where i<n then i<4..let us set i=3...hence 3 is not an element of ran(f)..with g:X->{1,2,3=n-1}...wouldn't we have 4 elements in X and 3 elements in the codomain?..how can this be one to one?

Answer (score 0):

Since the mapping $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is one-one, by definition it means that

${ \forall a,b\in X,\;\;a\neq b\Rightarrow f(a)\neq f(b)}$. Since the size of $X$ is $n$ it further means that $n$ different elements of $X$ map into $n$ different elements of $Y$. The size of $Y$ is also $n$ meaning that the mapping is also 'onto' since all elements of $Y$ have a pre-image in $X$.

Comment: This answer misses the point, which is how to define the function $g$. The comment from @amrsa nails it.

Comment: Indeed, but this answer still proves the 'theorem'.

Comment: the book requires proof by contradiction...so suppose f is not onto..etc...thanks anyways

Comment: If i understand the problem correctly...if we can find a function g:X->{1,..n-1} that is one to one...then n is no longer the least natural number for there to be a one to one function ..but n-1 ... however i still do not understand how we get to g...